# Can I use double monitors using my integrated graphics alongside my graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

I have a screen which has a broken HDMI, meaning it can only use VGA. I also have another, older screen which only has a VGA slot. I'd like to use both at once, but don't want to buy another graphics card if possible. Can I use the integrated graphics along with my [AMD Radeon R9 200 Series](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r9)?

Comment: You won't need to use integrated graphics if you have a graphics card as you mentioned. What ports does your R9 200 have? You'll most likely just need to get two adapters for the VGA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

But it really depends what you want to do with it.

If this is for simple desktop work then you shouldn't have any issues with this at all.

However, you may experience issues with the performance of the monitor connected to the integrated graphics card, as those typically do not have the same built-in hardware acceleration to properly handle 3D rendering or do not have the same amount/speed of graphics memory.

That being said, modern integrated graphics (as those found on [modern Intel CPU's](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hd-graphics/hd-graphics-developer.html)) aren't half bad and can run some demanding applications just fine. Furthermore, some applications support performing the 3D rendering on one graphics card and outputting on another.

Finally, as per MC10's comment, you can also get an HDMI or DisplayPort to VGA adapter or similar, for example:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/DisplayPort-Female-Adapter-Converter-Macbook/dp/B00SUP5Z0M/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1438090065&sr=8-2&keywords=displayport+VGA+adapter

Comment: Very nice edit by [qasdfdsaq](http://superuser.com/users/449623/qasdfdsaq) with some nice additional info and suggestions.

Comment: Hi, so when I plug both screens in, I get a no signal message on the monitor connected to the IGC. Is there something I have to enable in settings to get them to run together? (It is for simple desktop things)

Comment: Ben - you may need to enable onboard graphics in BIOS, as it could be disabled there. There might even be a setting which disables it when a dedicated graphics card is present. Refer to motherboard manual and/or manufacturer website for information about configuration. Or update your question with exact make and model and hope someone can point you in the right direction.